# UIButton text content keeps resetting every second update

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

I am trying to update a button with a test value and I have noticed that every second update the button title text shows the test value for a fraction of a second but then resets to the Button's default value.

It seems to be a bug, but I wanted to see if there is a simpler explanation. 
I have tried waiting up to 10 seconds before pushing the button but this seems to be consistently occurring.

Any ideas how to make UIButton function as expected?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var testEntry = "its working"
    @IBOutlet weak var testButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func runTest(sender:
        UIButton) {
        // The button value should equal the value of the label value, but every 2nd button press of the test button results in the title of the button value resetting to the default value
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.testLabel.text = "\(self.testEntry)"
            self.testButton.titleLabel?.text = "\(self.testEntry)"
        }
    }
```

[Here](https://github.com/grantkemp/bugWithUIButton/tree/master) is the github project.

Comment: setTitle method with state alwyz works , but directly setting value to tittlelabel sometime dint work

Comment: It sounds like the should remove the set title if the feature doesnt work consistently

Comment: I faced similar issue many times in objective C and Swift too , so shared my experience

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You shouldn't be directly setting the text of the button title label, you should only set the font directly onto the label. The text should be set by calling

```
func setTitle(_ title: String?, forState state: UIControlState)
```

The text toggles because you're selecting and de-selecting the button, which is switching between some of its states which have different titles.

Comment: thanks lovely explanation.  I actually had this issue previously but forgot. Apple should really fix this or deprecate it

Comment: Bug report filed with Apple. Attempts to assign the title text directly should fail to compile, as attempting to set a read-only property.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the button title text by using the following method...

```
self.testButton.setTitle(self.testEntry, forState: .Normal)
```

instead of `titleLabel` property.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
self.testButton.setTitle("hello", for: .normal)
```